# Garry's Mod Steam Server?

Tags: steam, linux, garrys-mod, hosting

I followed the following instructions for setting up a Garry's Mod server in Linux via the command line;

http://wiki.garrysmod.com/page/Hosting_A_Dedicated_Server

```
 mkdir ~/Steam
 cd ~/Steam 
 wget http://media.steampowered.com/client/steamcmd_linux.tar.gz
 tar -xvzf steamcmd_linux.tar.gz
 ./steamcmd.sh +login anonymous +force_install_dir ../gmodds +app_update 4020 validate +quit
```

Then I can run it with `./srcds_run -game garrysmod +maxplayers 32 +map gm_construct`

I can launch and play on my Garry's Mod server now, but how do I get additional game modes and maps? I really want a server running the game mode `Murder` on `CS_Office` but I can't figure out how to do it.

I have Counter Strike Source downloaded, but the maps haven't appeared in the maps folder. I also don't know where to download Murder from.

I can change the game mode to `Trouble in Terrorist Town` but only because it came preinstalled into the `gamemodes` folder, I'm not sure where to download other game modes though.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

You're looking for `+gamemode murder`.  You may need CSS: `./steamcmd.sh +app_update 232330 validate`.

I'm not sure if this will work, but if you try:

`./srcds_run -game garrysmod +maxplayers 32 +map cs_office +host_workshop_collection 187073946 -authkey`[YOUR_SECRET_API_KEY](http://steamcommunity.com/dev/apikey)`+gamemode murder`

Where **187073946** is the identifier for [Murder](http://steamcommunity.com/sharedfiles/filedetails/?id=187073946).

Be sure you have added CSS to your `gm/garrysmod/cfg/mount.cfg`:

> "cstrike" "/mnt/data/games/Steam/SteamApps/common/Counter-Strike Source Dedicated Server/cstrike"